# Can't dump to file despite mysqld running as root

Tags: mysql, wordpress

**TL;DR**

**I don't understand how `mysql` running as `root@localhost` would not be allowed to write to `/usr/lib/`? Writing a file there is a common step in going from SQL injection to `root` shell. Details below.**

On this challenge I'm doing, I've managed to gain admin access to a wordpress panel. From there I can edit php files, allowing me to run queries on the database at my leisure.

My first step was to check which user was running the mysql server:

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results( 'select system_user() ', OBJECT );
var_dump($results);
```

This showed that `mysql` is running as `root@localhost`. In my mind `root` should have *all* rights on the system. I confirmed that it had `FILE` permissions:

```
...  "'root'@'localhost'" ["privilege_type"]=> string(4) "FILE" ["is_grantable"]=> string(3) "YES" }
```

Just to be sure I tried to write a file to `/tmp/`:

```
select "hello world" into outfile "/tmp/test"
```

It worked. I now need a `root` shell on the system so [I proceeded to follow this methodology here](http://infamoussyn.com/2014/07/11/gaining-a-root-shell-using-mysql-user-defined-functions-and-setuid-binaries/) which involves writing a file to `/usr/lib/`:

```
select "hello world" into dumpfile "/usr/lib/test"
```

But I'm getting a permission-related error:

```
[Can't create/write to file '/usr/lib/raptor_udf2.so' (Errcode: 13)]
```

Using a web shell running as a low privilege user I checked the rights on `/usr/lib/`:

```
drwxr-xr-x 173 root root 53248 Sep 29  2011 lib
```

Nothing funky here, `root` should be able to write.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783313/how-can-i-get-around-mysql-errcode-13-with-select-into-outfile

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the *root MYSQL user* which doesn't have the permissions of the *root system user*.

Try giving the "mysql" user write permissions to the file.

Comment: Isn't `system_user()` supposed to return the user the `mysql` daemon is running as? I would assume it's returning the "system_user".

Comment: @Juicy this is an easy thing to check: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_system-user